# openssl - what is STACK_OF?

Tags: c, syntax, openssl

```
static STACK_OF(CMS_RevocationInfoChoice)
**cms_get0_revocation_choices(CMS_ContentInfo *cms)
{
    switch (OBJ_obj2nid(cms->contentType)) {

    case NID_pkcs7_signed:
        return &cms->d.signedData->crls;
```

[source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/de85a9de3f56aaf8c55c28fe495b900e50752a5a/crypto/cms/cms_lib.c#L561)

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208342/swig-openssl-1-0-problem-with-stack-of-macros) says it's

```
#define STACK_OF(type) struct stack_st_##type
```

But when I search the openssl code with regex `#define\s*STACK_OF` I do not find any entries.

What is `STACK_OF`?

Comment: In "safestack.h", there is a space between `#` and `define`, which is why your regex failed to match it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stacks" are the way OpenSSL handles a set/array of objects.  They are macro-accessed structures that provide the ability to operate on those objects.

[The `STACK_OF()` macro is defined as](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/aff636a4893e24bdc686a00a13ae6199dd38d6aa/include/openssl/safestack.h.in#L34):

```
# define STACK_OF(type) struct stack_st_##type
```

For the `X509` type, [the structure is defined as](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e1c2913833f84ccd23aa6f2001f1ecaccadf3e56/include/crypto/x509.h#L174):

```
struct x509_st {
    X509_CINF cert_info;
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;
      .
      .
      .
    char *propq;
} /* X509 */ ;
```

Per [the OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API):

> **STACK API**
>
> The stack library provides a generic way to handle collections of
> objects in OpenSSL. A comparison function can be registered to sort
> the collection.
>
> Interface is split in two headers, <openssl/stack.h> and
> <openssl/safestack.h>. The former declares the C functions that will
> execute the insert, delete, pop, push, and other operations on the
> stack, while the latter declares a bunch of macros to enforce some
> type-checking by the compiler; these macros are mostly auto-generated
> by mkstack.pl.
>
> It is highly discouraged to use the C functions declared in
> <openssl/stack.h>. Rather, use the macros defined in
> <openssl/safestack.h> for OpenSSL built-in stacks, and declare your
> own type-checking wrappers for your custom stacks.
>
> **Basic Use**
>
> A stack type is defined with the DECLARE_STACK_OF() macro and its
> instances are declared with the STACK_OF() macro.
>
> ...